# Please Explain How This Could Be Leaking - String Encoding Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i got a report from my analyser that this function could potentially be leaking. Can anyone shed any light as to why?

```
- (NSString *)encodeString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = NSMakeCollectable([(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) autorelease]);

    return newString;

}
```

Comment: Do you have an autorelease pool set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyser's suggestions about memory management aren't 100% accurate - this is why it uses the phrase "potentially be leaking". Don't forget that this analysis runs on the code and is not a runtime check. If you wish to make sure that this line doesn't leak, check this in instruments.

Comment: Correct, i never thought about this. Thanks.